# NullPointerException in ArrayList of images

Tags: android

I am getting a NullPointerException in the following line commented below.
Sometimes I get it (especially on first instance), sometimes I don't. So I am trying to solve this once and for all.
 
I retrieve the file path from an image database and then use bitmap decode on it. I am sure there are values in the database.

Thank you.

```
        ImageDB imagedb = new ImageDB(this);    
        imagedb.open();

        ArrayList<String> image_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        image_list.clear();

            if(imagedb.open() != null){
            Cursor tagcursor = imagedb.retrieveTag(tag);

             if(tagcursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    image_list.add(tagcursor.getString(tagcursor.getColumnIndex(tag)));

                }       
                while(tagcursor.moveToNext());

                }

             tagcursor.close();
           imagedb.close();
            }


                if(image_list != null && !image_list.isEmpty()){ 
            Collections.shuffle(image_list);

    if(image_list.get(0).toString() != null){ // nullpointerexception here or below if I comment here

                imagepath = image_list.get(0).toString(); 
            }

        }
```

This is the stack trace, but its just as a warning, the program still runs:

```
04-16 19:03:31.603: W/System.err(1355): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 19:03:31.613: W/System.err(1355):     at com.MucaaApps.imageUpdate.ImageService.setTag(ImageService.java:422)
04-16 19:03:31.613: W/System.err(1355):     at com.MucaaApps.ImageUpdate.imageService.setImageIcon(ImageService.java:377)
04-16 19:03:31.623: W/System.err(1355):     at com.MucaaApps.ImageUpdate.ImageService.onStart(ImageService.java:237)
04-16 19:03:31.623: W/System.err(1355):     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:306)
04-16 19:03:21.552: W/System.err(1355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2873)
04-16 19:03:21.552: W/System.err(1355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3500(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-16 19:03:21.552: W/System.err(1355):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
04-16 19:03:21.552: W/System.err(1355):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-16 19:03:21.552: W/System.err(1355):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-16 19:03:21.552: W/System.err(1355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-16 19:03:21.563: W/System.err(1355):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 19:03:21.563: W/System.err(1355):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-16 19:03:21.573: W/System.err(1355):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-16 19:03:21.573: W/System.err(1355):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-16 19:03:21.582: W/System.err(1355):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace? From your comment, it looks like there is nothing at index 0 of image_list, which would cause the `toString()` to throw a `NullPointerException`

Comment: @Nicholas, I have added the stack trace. It comes as a warning.As i say, it shows the NullPointerException on the line i commented.

Comment: Try putting break lines or output statements to verify that 1) `imagedb.open()` is not null, 2) `tagcursor` is not null or has values, 3) `image_list` has values after you attempt to populate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Answer. You added the value null to your ArrayList.

you can fix it so:

```
ImageDB imagedb = new ImageDB(this);
        imagedb.open();
        ArrayList<String> image_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        image_list.clear();

        if (imagedb.open() != null) {
            Cursor tagcursor = imagedb.retrieveTag(tag);

            if (tagcursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        final int index = tagcursor.getColumnIndex(tag)
                do {
                    final String val = tagcursor.getString(index);
                    if (val!=null){
                        image_list.add(val);
                    }

                } while (tagcursor.moveToNext());

            }

            tagcursor.close();
            imagedb.close();
        }

        if (image_list != null && !image_list.isEmpty()) {
            Collections.shuffle(image_list);

            if (image_list.get(0).toString() != null) { // nullpointerexception
                                                        // here or below if i
                                                        // comment here

                imagepath = image_list.get(0).toString();
            }

        }
```

Comment: I agree with this, however the real problem is likely somewhere further up. Whey did you put null values into your database to begin with? You might want to address that, as that may be an indication of a different problem

Comment: thats why i changed his code to avoid putting null into the list :-)

Comment: @Kyle.. i will have an thorough look to see if that's the case but i think i checked for null earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You are shuffling the list. So my guess is that one of filepaths is null and is randomly shuffled to the first position which leads to null pointer.

You could check it here

```
String filePath = tagcursor.getColumnIndex(tag);
if (filepath == null || filepath.isEmpty()) [
  //get additional info from cursor ..row id etc to debug
} else {
  image_list.add(filepath);
}
```